# vanilla javascript vs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble grasping the difference between the two. I tried downloading the library and there was no code. I am trying to build a basic slider along with other basic functions I have built in jQuery. Any help, tutorials, plugins and information would be very helpful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between jQuery and JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript)

Comment: http://vanilla-js.com/ is a joke site and not an actual framework

Answer (score 24):

"Vanilla JS" refers to plain, unmodified JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('myelement').innerHTML = "I was written with JavaScript!";
```

jQuery is a collection of functions and stuff that are intended to make it easier to write JavaScript (although personally I feel it makes it more like spaghetti)

```
$("#myelement").html("I was written with jQuery!");
```

Since jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript, plain JavaScript is ALWAYS faster to run. It may be harder to write because you have to actually think about what you're doing, but it will run faster than the same thing in jQuery.

For a comparison of the two code samples above, see [this JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/vanilla-js-vs-jquery)

Comment: +1 for "*you have to actually think about what you're doing*"

Answer (score 4):

javascript is built in to the browser

and you can just link to the online versions of jquery and jqueryui to start with

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

and the slider is in jquery ui library - (it is a library built on top of and dependant on jquery)
so bring that in next

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

then the samples from jqueryui should make more sense

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

from

http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: And yes, it turns out the vanilla-js site is just a bit of a laugh

Comment: I am pretty familiar with using jQuery UI and jQuery plugins, I was looking for more information and how to go about implementing vanilla javascript to build a slider and other basic functions.

Comment: Oh OK, sorry. I see what you mean now. It would be a lot of work. A lot of css and canvas stuff i imagine.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a library based on JavaScript. It provides short-hand methods of things that could be otherwise coded in JavaScript. jQuery is coded in JavaScript, and is not built-in inside the browser, so you have to embed it.

jQuery UI, on the other hand, is a UI library which allows you to codes basic UI elements in a short-hand manner.

You didn't specify which one you were utilizing.

To embed jQuery, use this for the latest jQuery version:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

and this for the latest UI version:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Note that the examples above our hosted on jQuery.com.

Google also offers a hosted jQuery solution via developers.google.com.

You can also self-host jQuery on your own server (if you have any). Some people think that using Google's servers (or jQuery's) is quite faster then hosting it on your own server, but it's you to run tests and discover which one works best/faster for you.

Because jQuery is an external library (an extension of JavaScript), you have to load it, it's not built into the browser, therefore it's always slower.

Though some people think that due to the fact that jQuery is (for some), much easier to code (and the transitions like FadeIn are built-in), that it's worth the slower loading time.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**  You also mentioned that you downloaded JavaScript and that there was no code inside, but JavaScript is built-in inside the browser so there's no download of it. You're probably referring to [this joke](http://vanilla-js.com/).